# Chi-Square Density Graph in R

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared

How can I plot a chi-square density graph in R?

I got the following codes but I'm not sure how to manipulate them:

```
curve( dchisq(x, df=28), col='red', main = "Chi-Square Density Graph",
          from=0,to=60)
xvec <- seq(7.5,60,length=101)
pvec <- dchisq(xvec,df=28)
polygon(c(xvec,rev(xvec)),c(pvec,rep(0,length(pvec))),
        col=adjustcolor("black",alpha=0.3))
```

Could someone explain what the codes mean?

Comment: Manipulate it how? The code you posted plots a chi-square distribution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to ask a better question please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4):

The package ggplot2 provides an easy way to plot Chi square distributions. You have to simply specify a `stat_function` with `dchisq` as your function and then a list to `args` that indicates the degrees of freedom.

For example, here is sample code for a Chi square distribution for 4 degrees of freedom:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 20)), aes(x = x)) +
     stat_function(fun = dchisq, args = list(df = 4))
```